# firefox rendering issue

Tags: firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- load jquery and load it before anything else -->

    <!----------------------------------- Developement links ------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqueryValidator/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<title>
</title></head>
```

I have above in a web page all browsers understands it correctly, but firefox prints
----------------------------------- Developement links -------------------------------------------------------------
On top of page, what is wrong here?

Comment: The validator is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
<!-- Development links -->
```

Or use something other than a dash, it's used to indicate the end and start of a comment, multiple dashes may confuse the user agent.

```
<!-- ******************************* Development links ************************* -->
```

You might be able to have a space between the first 2 dashes and consequent dashes as well, I would just use asterisks.